# how to decode json emoji in android

Tags: java, android, json, emoji

I used compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4' not worked

my json emoji is like :

```
|ud83d|ude00                      
|ud83d|ude01                      
|ud83d|ude02                      
|ud83d|ude03                      
|ud83d|ude04                      
|ud83d|ude05                      
|ud83d|ude06                      
|ud83d|ude09                      
|ud83d|ude0a                      
|ud83d|ude0b                      
|ud83d|ude0e                      
|ud83d|ude0d                      
|ud83d|ude18                      
|ud83d|ude17
```

I dont find any way .
I just find >>  https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/67374.html 
but i dont want how convert to this format by code

Comment: ohh no suggestion !

Comment: Have you tried this library? https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments you should use an excellent [emoji-java](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java) library.
First of all add required dependency - Maven, for example, would look like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
        <artifactId>emoji-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then, you should change the json, since emoji uses backslash (`\`) not a pipe (`|`).

After that you can parse the file like so (Java 8):

```
List<String> collect = Files.lines(Paths.get("filePath"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .map(StringEscapeUtils::unescapeJava)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
collect.forEach(s -> System.out.println(EmojiManager.getByUnicode(s).getUnicode()));
```

Java 7:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\untitled\\src\\main\\resources\\emoji.txt"))) {

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(EmojiManager.getByUnicode(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(line)).getUnicode());
     }

} catch (IOException e) {
      // error handling
}
```

Note, that you should use [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava-java.lang.String-) in order to retrieve correct values from file.